# AWS rekognition x,y formula

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, numbers, amazon-rekognition

I am attempting to find the x,y coordinates for the nose of a person in a photo with AWS rekognition, im using the javascript SDK and am getting returned the values as a ratio of the size of the picture. This is clearly stated in the documentation and I have no problem with that.

What I am after is a formula to find the exact x,y of the nose "landmark" from the perspective of the whole image, not the bounding box. below is my output from rekognition.

```
{ FaceDetails: 
   [ { BoundingBox: 
        { Width: 0.6399999856948853,
          Height: 0.47999998927116394,
          Left: 0.1644444465637207,
          Top: 0.17666666209697723 },
       Landmarks: 
        [ { Type: 'eyeLeft',
            X: 0.36238425970077515,
            Y: 0.3900916874408722 },
          { Type: 'eyeRight', X: 0.5580493807792664, Y: 0.362303763628006 },
          { Type: 'nose', X: 0.4164798855781555, Y: 0.4511926472187042 },
          { Type: 'mouthLeft',
            X: 0.42259901762008667,
            Y: 0.5591621994972229 },
          { Type: 'mouthRight',
            X: 0.5580134391784668,
            Y: 0.5394133925437927 } ],
       Pose: 
        { Roll: -9.781778335571289,
          Yaw: -20.029239654541016,
          Pitch: 10.893087387084961 },
       Quality: { Brightness: 59.32780456542969, Sharpness: 99.9980239868164 },
       Confidence: 99.99403381347656 } ] }
```

I have an image that is 2576x1932 is there some formula that can be applied here to just give me the x,y of the nose in the picture. currently it gives the x,y of the nose from inside the bounding box (i think). My math skill is not really up to this one.

From the documentation:

Boundingbox:

> The top and left values returned are ratios of the overall image size.
>   For example, if the input image is 700x200 pixels, and the top-left
>   coordinate of the bounding box is 350x50 pixels, the API returns a
>   left value of 0.5 (350/700) and a top value of 0.25 (50/200).

Landmark:

> x-coordinate from the top left of the landmark expressed as the ration
>   of the width of the image. For example, if the images is 700x200 and
>   the x-coordinate of the landmark is at 350 pixels, this value is 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X/Y values that Rekognition returns are simply percentages of the width/height of the image.  Per the Rekognition API documentation, the landmark positions are relative to the entire image, not the bounding box.

Therefore, all you have to do is multiply the width of the image by the X value of the landmark to get the X position of that landmark (and then multiply the height of the image by the Y position of the landmark to get the Y position of the landmark in pixels).

The reason Rekognition does this is so that the position of the nose (for example) is the same no matter the pixel size of the image.  In your example above, the nose is located at:

```
 { Type: 'nose', X: 0.4164798855781555, Y: 0.4511926472187042 },
```

Which simply means it's at 41.6% of the width of the image across starting at the left border, and 45.1% of the height of the image down starting at the top border.  Multiply those percentages by your actual width and height to get pixel coords.

See:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Landmark.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Bounding boxes from recognition data to index or label. I have done for faces

```
#python
widtho = 717 #width of the given image
heighto = 562 #height of the given image
width = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Width')
height = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Height')
left = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Left')
top = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Top')
w = int(width * widtho)
h = int(height * heighto)
x = int(left * widtho)
y = int(top * heighto)
cv2.rectangle(imagere, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

This will get the bounding boxes.. hope I gave some clue  on formula